# Jquery datepicker not working on elements inside class given

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

If i use this then its working.

```
<td ><div> Timestamp: </div><input type="text" value="" class="datepicker"/></td>
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

This above code is working but this is not working

```
<td  class="datepicker" ><div> Timestamp: </div><input type="text" value=""/></td>
    $( ".datepicker input" ).datepicker();
```

Comment: How about `$("input", ".datepicker").datepicker();`, and did you wrap that in a document ready function ??

Comment: yes , i have wrapped that. that is also not working

Comment: @undefined actually i have input element inside the td and that is dynamically generated so i can't add the class

Comment: And you are of course initalizing the datepicker after those elements are generated, and not before when they don't yet exists?

Comment: if the first one is working , it means there is no problem with initializing

Comment: [Working here](http://jsfiddle.net/hWTmh/) and [not working here](http://jsfiddle.net/hWTmh/1/), is this the case ?

Comment: @Sheikh    , i think your right. what did that happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both correct. Do you have some malformed HTML elsewhere on the page? Is a JavaScript error being thrown before .datepicker() is called?

Comment: i think u r right. i had the malformed html and it worked , when i corrected that

Answer (score 1):

Both ok.

Try to use web develop tools and step into the code to find out the errors.

Answer (score 0):

try using following selector:

```
$("td.datepicker input:text").datepicker();
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/Sy4zx/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the child selector **>**

```
 $(".datepicker > input").datepicker();
```